# Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")

Tags: linux, shell

Error messages:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
/sbin/modprobe.sh: 2: /sbin/modprobe.sh: EOF: not found
/sbin/modprobe.sh: 10: /sbin/modprobe.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

Shell script:

```
EOF
#!/bin/bash

if [[ \$1 == -l ]]
then

if [ -z \$2 ]    
then
find /lib/modules/\$(uname -r) -name '*.ko' | sed -e "s#\\/lib\/modules\/\$(uname -r)\/##g"
else
find /lib/modules/\$(uname -r) -name '*.ko' | sed -e "s#\/lib\/modules\/\$(uname -r)\/##g" | grep \$2
fi

else
/sbin/modprobe \$@
fi
EOF
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. What are all the backslashes there for?  Please show us exactly what you're doing! It looks a bit as if you have some here documents in use.  The initial `EOF` is generating the `EOF: not found` (but that says it is on line 2, not line 1 as shown in your script). I don't see how line 10 (an `else` line) would generate the `Syntax error: "(" unexpected` error either.  It is hard enough to debug programs without having to guess what the source code actually looks like.

Comment: Ignoring the EOF, `\$2` is a non-empty string, so the `\$(uname -r)` in the else clause (with a `(` following an escaped `$`) is the cause of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your script, rewritten to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ x$1 = x-l ] ; then

    BASE=/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/

    if [ x$2 = x ] ; then
        find $BASE -name '*.ko' | sed -e "s#$BASE##g"
    else
        find $BASE -name '*.ko' | sed -e "s#$BASE##g" | grep $2
    fi

else
    /sbin/modprobe $@
fi
```

Your main problem was a ton of backslashes that broke the script.  If you are using `$(command)` to get the output of a command, you need that dollar sign to be left alone; `\$(command)` will turn into a literal string `"$(command)"` which isn't what you wanted.  Likewise, your `sed` command lines are using the `#` character to delimit the search and replace strings, so you don't need to put a backslash before the slashes in the paths.  Likewise, you need to just have `$2` for the second argument; `\$2` is the literal string `"$2"`.

I used a common convention for testing the `$1` and `$2` arguments: I put an `x` before them in the test.  This works even in old wacky UNIX shells.  I guess with a GNU Bash on Linux you can count on the `[` operator being built-in, but doing it this way still works.

Also note how I indented the `if`/`else` statements.  This is purely a style thing and you don't have to do things the way I do, but I find this to be the most readable.

Finally, this script is approaching the level of complexity where I would consider rewriting it in a more powerful language than Bash.  I personally prefer Python but you could use Ruby or whatever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you! I did not understand the problem.